# Android DarkMode textColor not changed inside RecyclerView's row file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dark-theme

I have set the recycler view and set one `textview` with simple text in row file of `RecyclerView`.

I have set the `fragment` according to tab mean I have used the `BottomNavigationView` and there is one `fragment` which contains the `RecyclerView`.

And I have set the `android:forceDarkAllowed="true"` inside the xml file.

I have applied the `DayNight` theme.

The color of the `textview` which is inside the fragment's xml can be update according to dark and light theme, but the adapter's item(Used for the `RecyclerView`) which contains the `textview` that not changed the color.

Pref. XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/txt"
        android:text="@string/preferences"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
public class PreferencesFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String TAG = "PreferencesFragment";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RecyclerView rvList = view.findViewById(R.id.rvList);

        rvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DarkThemeApplication.context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        rvList.setAdapter(new RVListAdapter());
    }

    class RVListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RVListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater
                .from(DarkThemeApplication.context).inflate(R.layout.row_txt, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RVListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 50;
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Row File XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/txt"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:text="asdasdasdas" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> LayoutInflater
>             .from(DarkThemeApplication.context).inflate(R.layout.row_txt, ...
> ```

Use an `Activity` context and not an `Application` one for inflating your views.

Your adapter is a non-static inner class in a `Fragment` so you can just replace `DarkThemeApplication.context` with `requireActivity()`.

Comment: Yes, it's working, Thanks @laalto for the quick response.